# When should I NOT use an article in front of a noun? Easy to remember tips?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

THE title says all. Although I've been living in the US for many years at this point, this still confuses me time to time.

Comment: When do you think you need them before a noun?

Comment: Maybe in general, *Titles* say it all, but here specifically, *The title* says it all.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Ha. That made me chuckle. If I am trying to say: "... in the midst of multiple projects..." Should I put "the" in front of "multiple" here? If so, why?

Comment: You should look on ELL. Cheers.

Comment: @Lambie why bother to comment if you are not going to be helpful?

Comment: Because there are rules here for easy questions which the moderators usually migrate to ELL. I did say cheers. However, the topic is a long one and somewhat laborious.

Comment: @Lambie can you please provide me with the link? Apologies; I thought you were just telling me to visit English Language Learners ("ELL") sites.

Comment: Go to the last icon on the right at the top of the page. Click on it. Find Help and click on that. As you can see, a moderator removed  your comment as it was not an answer.

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, I noticed. Thank you for the directions!